# when to use elem.style.left o r elem.offsetLeft

Tags: javascript

When you are trying to get the left value of an element, what is the difference between elem.style.left or elem.offsetLeft in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

the difference is that `elem.offsetLeft` is a *computed value* of left offset, calculated by browser even if you haven't specified explictly the same property via style and/or CSS, instead `elem.style.left` it's a get of property *left* of *style* attribute

try this code: http://jsfiddle.net/nnryG/

the computedValue is unitless, the style property is what you assigned in **inline** style.

Comment: when you say unitless, it just returns a number? while left would return value + px?

Comment: so am i better off just sticking to offsetLeft?

Comment: steve, try the link above :) the statements do different things, ther's no a better one. It depends on what you're trying to accomplish.